# RxJS Observable: Subscription lost?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, angular2-observables

What is the difference between the following two observable mappings?

(if something in the following code appears strange to you: it stems from a learning-by-doing hobby project; I still learn RxJS)

I have a component with a getter and a constructor. Both read information from the app's ngrx store and extract a string (`name`).

**The only difference between the getter and the constructor:** the getter is used in the HTML and the observable it returns is sent through an `async` pipe, whereas the observable mapping in the constructor is finished by a subscription using `subscribe`. I expect both of them to fire as often as a new value for `name` becomes available.

But instead only the getter works that way and provides the `async` pipe in the HTML where it is used with new values of name (`console.log('A')` is called for every name change). The `subscribe` subscription's callback is called only once: `console.log('B')` and `console.log('B!')` are both called exactly once and never again.

How can this difference in behavior be explained?

Snippet from my component:

```
// getter works exactly as expected:
get name$(): Observable<string> {
  console.log('getter called')
  return this.store
    .select(this.tableName, 'columns')
    .do(_ => console.log('DO (A)', _))
    .filter(_ => !!_)
    .map(_ => _.find(_ => _.name === this.initialName))
    .filter(_ => !!_)
    .map(_ => {
      console.log('A', _.name)
      return _.name
    })
}

// code in constructor seems to lose the subscription after the subscription's first call:
constructor(
  @Inject(TablesStoreInjectionToken) readonly store: Store<TablesState>
) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.store
      .select(this.tableName, 'columns')
      .do(_ => console.log('DO (B)', _))
      .filter(_ => !!_)
      .map(_ => _.find(_ => _.name === this.initialName))
      .filter(_ => !!_)
      .map(_ => {
        console.log('B', _.name)
        return _.name
      })
      .subscribe(_ => console.log('B!', _))
  })
}
```

Additional information: If I add `ngOnInit`, this life cycle hook is called exactly once during the whole test. If I move the subscription from the constructor to the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook, it does not work any better than from within the constructor. Exactly the same (unexpected) behavior. The same applies to `ngAfterViewInit` and further life cycle hooks.

Output for the name changes `'some-name' -> 'some-other-name' -> 'some-third-name' -> 'some-fourth-name' -> 'some-fifth-name'`:

[UPDATE] as suggested by Pace in their comment, I added getter call logs

[UPDATE] `do`s added as suggested by Pace

```
getter called
DO (A) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
A some-name
DO (B) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
B some-name
B! some-name
getter called
DO (A) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
A some-other-name
getter called
DO (A) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
A some-third-name
getter called
DO (A) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
A some-fourth-name
getter called
DO (A) (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
A some-fifth-name
```

Example content of the output printed by the `console.log`s in the `do`s:

```
[
  {
    "name": "some-name"
  },
  {
    "name": "some-other-name"
  },
  {
    "name": "some-third-name"
  }
]
```

Seems as if the `subscribe` subscription gets lost after its first call. But why?

Comment: It's a good question.  Nothing jumps out at me in the code you've show that could be an issue.  I assume both of these methods are part of the same class?  I might put a debug print statement inside the getter to see how many times the getter is called.  Maybe the difference is that the getter is being called more than once and setting up a new observable chain each time?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. I just tried it and added the getter calls to the output. Now I need to find out who unsubscribes my subscription...

Comment: I think it is more likely the observable chain is completing than something unsubscribing you.  You can confirm this theory by adding a third callback to `subscribe`.  Unfortunately, I don't know ngrx-store well enough to know what would cause `select` to complete.  The rest of the operators are simple chaining operators that shouldn't trigger completion.

Comment: Neither an error callback passed to `subscribe` nor a "complete" callback passed to this call are executed.

Comment: Could it be Angular prematurely destroying my observable chain? Even though `ngOnDestroy` is never called? The component lives in a popup window and `ngOnDestroy` is not called until the popup window is closed. But the name changes are triggered while the popup is open.

Comment: Can you use `do` right after the select to see if the new events are getting filtered out?

Comment: I added the `do`s. They fire exactly as often as the `map`s/`subscribe`. But thank you for the hint. I did not know that I could use `do` that way.

Comment: Is anything changing the value of `initialName`?

Comment: Isn't your module lazyloaded?

Comment: Could you possibly show your reducer code? I'm wondering if you are mutating the store value in your reducer rather than returning a new value? This could mean that the ngrx store is never sending any updates (and so only the getter method logs the changes as it is constantly being resubscribed to)

Comment: @ideaboxer did you get your solution? Also what version of ngrx are you using 1.x or 4.x as that would make a difference.  In my experience it is usually unnecessary to subscribe while using ngrx.  The store will return an observable and you pass that observable piped 'async' to your presentation component that way the store handles the subscribing and unsubscribing.

Comment: @Woot In most of the cases I send my observables into `async` pipes. But in this case I need a second, "manual" subscription to set selection and focus of an input field. The text in the input field should be selected and the input field should get the focus whenever the observable fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Observable returned from `ngrx.select()` will only fire when the data in the store has changed.

If you want the Observable to fire when `initialName` changes, then I would recommend converting initialName into an RXJS `Subject` and using `combineLatest`:

```
initialNameSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('some-name');

constructor(
  @Inject(TablesStoreInjectionToken) readonly store: Store<TablesState>
) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.store
      .select(this.tableName, 'columns')
      .combineLatest(this.initialNameSubject)
      .map(([items, initialName]) => items.find(_ => _.name === initialName))
      .filter(_ => !!_)
      .map(_ => {
        console.log('B', _.name)
        return _.name
      })
      .subscribe(_ => console.log('B!', _))
  })
}
```

Comment: Well that is the solution. Many thanks. Since whenever before I expect the name to change, not the `columns` field is changed but only the `selectedColumn` field (which I did not mention in my question since I did not think of its influence on the problem), the store does not fire an event to this selection of the `columns` field. I did not take into account that it is still called once because of the subscription.

Answer (score 11):

You should never use a getter like that. Do **not** return an Observable from a getter.

Angular will unsubscribe/subscribe again and again, everytime a **[change detection cycle](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)** happens (which happens a lot).

*For now on I'll write "CD" for "change detection"*

Simple demo of that:

Take a really simple component:

```
// only here to mock a part of the store
const _obsSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject('name 1');

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  get obs$() {
    return _obsSubject$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(tap(x => console.log('getting a new value')));
  }

  randomFunction() {
    // we don't care about that, it's just
    // to trigger CD from the HTML template
  }
}
```

You'll see `getting a new value` in your console, and every time you click on the button "Click to trigger change detection", which has a `(click)` event registered, it'll trigger a new CD cycle.

And, as many times as you click on that button, you'll see that you are getting twice `getting a new value`.
(twice is because we're not in production mode and Angular performs 2 CD cycles to make sure the variable has not changed between the first and the second change detection, which might lead to problems but that's another story).

The point of **an observable** is that it can **remains open for a long time** and you should take advantage of that.
In order to refactor the previous code to keep the subscription opened and avoid unsubscribing/subscribing again, we can just get rid of the getter and declare a public variable (accessible by the template):

```
// only here to mock a part of the store
const _obsSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject('name 1');

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  obs$ = _obsSubject$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(tap(x => console.log('getting a new value')));

  randomFunction() {
    // we don't care about that, it's just
    // to trigger CD from the HTML template
  }
}
```

And now, no matter how many times you click on the button, you'll see one and only one `getting a new value` (until the observable emits a new value of course), but the change detection will **not** trigger a new subscription.

Here's a live demo on **Stackblitz** so you can play around and see the `console.log` happening =)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e42ilu

**EDIT:**
A `getter` is a function, and thus, Angular has to call it on every CD to check if there's a new value coming from it that should be updated in the view. This costs a lot, but it's the principle and the "magic" of the framework. That's also why you should avoid running intensive CPU tasks in function that might be triggered on every CD. If it's a pure function (same input same output AND no side effects), use a pipe because they're considered "pure" by default and cache the results. For the same arguments they will run the function in the pipe only once, cache the result and then just return the result instantly without running the function again.

Comment: You just gave a very detailed answer on an issue / question I was having yesterday with the behavior of observables from a variable vs from a getter, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've qlso qdded some more info about getter/pure pipe and perfs, see edit.

Comment: Let me know if this helps to solve your current problem or if you need further info

Comment: The getter has a very particular meaning: It is an experiment to avoid any write access to the value while avoiding premature execution of the observable chain. If I write it as you suggest, the `select` call will throw an error since the store is not ready when the component instance is constructed. If I assign the observable later, say, in `ngOnInit`, I cannot make `name$` a `readonly` member which sabotages my efforts to make the class as immutable as possible.

Comment: Though the getter might not provide the best performance, it is the only way of making the member `name$` a `readonly` one. Better solutions are always welcome, as long as they preserve immutability of this observable reference and do not make the app crash.

Comment: (I have to add that the getter does not lead to any noticeable performance losses; which are usually indicators that the code needs to be improved)