# RxJS: forkJoin seems not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently using `combineLatest()` method to get all my friends and make it as a list. However, it produces an ordering issue when I try to remove an item from the beginning. *(View does not render correctly)* Therefore, I'd like to switch from `combineLatest()` to `forkJoin()` to get all the friends at once.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

friends$: Observable<User[]>;

getMyFriendList() {
  this.friends$ = this.userService.getMyFriendsId().switchMap(friendKeys => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(friendKeys.map(user => this.userService.getFriends(user.key)));
  });
}
```

But nothing happens when I call forkJoin(). What am I doing wrong here?

```
getMyFriendsId() {
  let friendRef = this.getFriendRef(this.currentUserId);
  this.friends$ = friendRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => ({ key: a.payload.doc.id, ...a.payload.doc.data()}));
  });
  return this.friends$;
}

getFriends(uid: string) {
  return this.getUsersRef(uid).valueChanges();
}
```

**EDIT**

`getMyFriendsId()` updates a new data when a logged in user remove another user in the friend list.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>Friends <span class="total-friends"></span></ion-list-header>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let user of friends$ | async">
        <ion-item *ngIf="user" (click)="viewUserProfile(user)">
          <ion-avatar (click)="showOriginalAvatarImage()" item-start>
            <img-loader [src]="user.thumbnailURL" [spinner]="true"></img-loader>
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>{{user.displayName}}</h2>
          <p>{{user.statusMessage}}</p>
        </ion-item>
             ...
<ion-list>
```

**Lifecycle event**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.;
  this.getMyFriendList();
}
```

Comment: I do not know how you're using/calling `getMyFriendList()` but if you're assigning a new reference every time to `this.friends$` it's not a good idea and you should take a look into a similar question I've answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579837/2398593

Comment: @Maxime I’m currently using Ionic framework, and calling getMyFriendList() in ionViewWillEnter() which is a lifecycle event.  Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you read the answer from the link I've copied in previous answer?

Comment: @Maxime Yes I’ve read and up-voted your post. I’ve learned a few things I didn’t even know before. But I’m still a bit confused :(

Comment: how often is `getMyFriendList` called?

Comment: also, are you subscribing to `this.friends$` somewhere?

Comment: @Maxime I've just updated my post. I think `getMyFriendList` is called every time when the user removes his or her friend user in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164505/discussion-between-jeffminsungkim-and-maxime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) combines all the observables, and will only emit the values if *all* observables are **COMPLETED**. The reason your code doesn't work is because a you are using `valueChanges()`, and it is a type of event that will never complete -- they are forever listening to the changes of the value!

If you really want to use `.forkJoin` (or to prove the point), add a `take(1)` into your `valueChanges`:

```
getFriends(uid: string) {
  return this.getUsersRef(uid).valueChanges().take(1);
}
```

The above code will work because it forcefully **completes** the observable with `take()`, but obviously will defeat the purpose because your code will only work once. Conclusion is if you want to keep on observing for a change of a particular value, and combine it with another observable, yes, use `combineLatest()`

Comment: Thank you, @CozyAzure. A very clear answer indeed! I should stick with `combineLatest()`. I've posted my current problem in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560821/rxjs-returns-an-empty-observable-although-an-array-is-not-empty). Can you please tell me why this is happening and how can I resolve this issue?